# How to make each row fetch using SQL query as list objects?

Tags: python, sql

```
def SelectData(self):
    query = "Select * from python_training.rules"
    curr = self.con.cursor()
    curr.execute(query)
    for row in curr:
        result = row
        print(result)
```

The above function returns :

```
(1, 'CU_GFC_ID', '11A')
(2, 'GFCID', '10')
(1, 'GFCID', '11')
```

How to make each row as a individual list object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code **convert result to list**:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2], 'col2':['a','b']})


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

df.to_sql(name='df', con=conn, index=False)

print('{:9} | {:^9}'.format('tuple', 'list'))

def SelectData():
    query = "Select * from df"
    curr = conn.cursor()
    curr.execute(query)
    for row in curr:
        result = list(row)
        print('{:9} | {:9}'.format(str(row), str(result)))
  
SelectData()
```

Output:

[image]